# How to pronounce "AKA"?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

How do you pronounce the acronym *AKA* (*also known as*)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I pronounce it *ay-kay-ay* /ˌeɪkeɪˈeɪ/. Or I just say, "also known as".

Answer (score 6):

I say A. K. A. (like Reg posted at the same time) http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/aka

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Also interesting.  I've heard it occasionally as /ækæ/ but never with a long vowel.

Comment: ækæ would be /ˌeɪkeɪˈeɪ/ or a fast A.K.A. as I posted, no?

Comment: No, [æ] is a short vowel as in "cat" rather than the diphthong /eɪ/ as in "hay"

Answer (score 3):

"AKA" is an initialism, not an acronym. Acronyms are pronounced as words (i.e. SCUBA); initialisms are read one letter at a time. Initialisms and acronyms are types of abbreviation.

Comment: Close but not quite. Words read one letter at a time are called *initialisms*. You said "abbreviated words are read one letter at a time." Abbreviated words (abbreviations) include *both* acronyms *and* initialisms.

Answer (score -2):

I pronounce it "acker". (Silent R of course.) Simple, quick, just like how I say "fack" for FAQ.

Comment: How hard is it,to say "Eff Ae Cue"?! :D

Comment: @abhiii5459 - Don't you mean "How FAQing hard is it?"