# Are "i.e." and "e.g." initialisms?

Tags: abbreviations, latin, initialisms

I was told that abbreviations consist of initialisms (*FBI*, *a.k.a.*†), acronyms (*NATO*, ), and shortened words (*ad*, *bike*).

† *Thanks to Pete Kirkham for correcting me: for most people a.k.a. is an initialism.*

But what about *i.e.* and *e.g.*? At the first glance, they look as initialisms, but typically we pronounce them as "for example" and "that is", not literally, like "eye ee".

So which subclass of abbreviations they belong to? Initialisms or maybe something different, and why? Are there reputable sources to classify them?

Comment: I myself say "E-G" and "I-E" when I come across those terms; this is similar to how &c. is pronounced "And-C." It seems to be an initialism, and the use of saying "for example," &c., is something that arose out of common speech, since it is commonly accepted that those initialisms mean the longer phrases.

Comment: They are initialisms, but for Latin, not English: *id est* (that is) and *exempli grati* (for example).

Comment: @DanBron Sure, they are initialisms for Latin. But what about English? :)

Comment: a.k.a is an initialism, at least for most people - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14588/how-to-pronounce-aka/14634

Comment: @BigRigz I'm a foreigner, but it seems that a practice to pronounce _i.e._ and _e.g._ literally is not the most common one: "True, there are a few people who actually say 'ee-jee' for the last one, but this practice is decidedly unusual." - prof. Larry Trask, 1997, http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/capsandabbr/abbr

Comment: It may have been unusual in the circles in which Trask moved. I don't think it is. When people read a text, in my experience they are more likely to read "ee-gee" if that is what is written. In normal speech, of course, when merely providing examples and not reading a text, people use "for example".

Comment: @johnc.j. Nothing wrong about escaping convention; best to be unique.

Comment: I (British, 60+) say 'ee gee' and 'eye-ee', but I pronounce both _etc._ and _&c_ as 'etcetera'.

Comment: @BigRigz I've never heard anyone say "and c."  I would pronounce it "etcetera."  But then I've never seen "&c" in anything printed after the 18th century.  But I do say "eye ee" and "ee gee," because the Latin phrases of which they are the initial letters are not widely known today.  In my own writing I make a point of using "that is" and "for example."

Comment: @DanBron that's _exempli gratia._

Comment: Why does it matter whether they are initialisms? What depends on how they are classified?

Comment: @jsw29 In short, this is because I work on a technical manual about naming files. I have some examples there that should be placed in a well-defined order, and that order depends on this classification. I already found a workaround to solve this case, but I think that the question itself is OK enough to not delete or close it.

Answer (score 1):

My trusty Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS), 13th ed. calls *e.g.* and *i.e.* "Abbreviations" under the heading of "Scholarship".

## Scholarship

> 14.31 Abbreviations have a very long history of use in the realm of scholarship, and general principles concerning their use are widely agreed upon.
>
> > ...
> > General abbreviations such as *etc., e.g.,* and *i.e.* are preferable confined to parenthetical references.

When pronouncing the first, one could say "eye ee", "*id est*", or "that is."

When pronouncing the second, one could say "ee gee", "*exempli gratia*", or "for example."

(This AE speaker prefers the English translation of the Latin, but has heard all three pronounced.)

CMoS calls these *abbreviations*. I suppose if you had to subclassify them, you might call them *scholarly abbreviations*.

Comment: I’m probably wrong, but I always thought scribal/scholarly abbreviations were to be read out in full, not 
pronounced as individual letters—and usually into English not their Latin originals.  
So ‘&’ is pronounced *and* not *et*; ‘pp.’ is *pages* not *pee-pee* or
*paginae*; ‘c.’ is *circa* or *around* not *see*; ‘ff.’ is *and the
following* not *eff-eff*; ‘v.s.’ and ‘v.i.’ are *see above/below* not *vee-ess/eye*; ‘et al.’ is *and others* not *et
alii/alios/alia/aliae* let alone *Ed-Al* the man’s name; ‘cf.’ is *compare*
not *confer*; ‘viz.’ is *namely* not *vizz* or *weedy lick it*. :)

Comment: Funny, yes, I will read out loud "pp. 14-18" as *pages 14 to 18*, never *pee pee*.  But if I read out loud "all mammals (e.g., elephants)" I will say *all mammals, for example elephants*. But when reading an academic paper in my head, I don't bother to translate the abbreviation into English, and just read, *all mammals, ee gee elephants*. I have heard others speak *ee gee* and *eye ee*, even though my preference is to speak English, thank you.

Comment: Are you implying by omission that e.g. and i.e. are -not- initialisms? That is does CMoS only talk about abbreviations in general or does it separate into initialisms and acronyms and eg/ie are explicitly stated as not an initialism?

Comment: CMoS 13th ed. does not have *initialisms*. It classifies *i.e., e.g., ibid., ca.,* and *etc.* as abbreviations. In the index for acronyms it has a *See also* Abbreviations and vv. (Yes, *vice versa*)

Comment: The question was whether they are initialisms. **That** question cannot be answered by referring to a manual that does not use the concept of an initialism. One may believe that the absence of the concept from this manual indicates that the question, as posed, is misguided, but that is not obvious; it would need to be argued for.